# Phonegap Camera application crash

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing an application for Android using PhoneGap (Cordova 1.6.1). My application crashes when I invoke the camera API and I am getting log messages like "showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection". I have used the following methods to invoke the camera:

```
function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }


 function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {        
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage'); 
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';      
     smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;    
    }

function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used it like this and it is working fine for me. Please check -

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {

console.log("CORDOVA IS WORKING:::");
}

        function capturePhoto()
{
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI }); 
}

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate method of my activity class I have set a Javascript interface:

```
appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "GC");
```

And I have created a method for cleaning the garbage collector:

```
public void cleanGC() {
        System.gc();
    }
```

In my .js file, I call the previous method before to call the camera or the picture gallery:

```
GC.cleanGC();
```